# How to print another System.out.println results in a JTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield

I recently completed an assignment that asked us to sort names out of a text file alphabetically, I used three different classes to get it to work properly.

```
class Person {
String firstName;
String lastName;
}
```

I then created this to sort in to alphabetical order by last name and then by first name

```
 class SortNames {

 void sortNames(Person[] arr, int type) {
 if (type == 1) {
 int j;
 boolean flag = true; // will determine when the sort is finished
 Person temp;
 while (flag) {
 flag = false;

 for (j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
 if (arr[j].lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(arr[j + 1].lastName) > 0) { // ascending
                                                                           // sort
  temp = arr[j];
  arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; // swapping
  arr[j + 1] = temp;
  flag = true;
     }
   }
  }
 for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
 System.out.println(arr[k].firstName +" "+arr[k].lastName);
 } else if (type == 2) {

  int j;
  boolean flag = true; // will determine when the sort is finished
  Person temp;
  while (flag) {
  flag = false;
  for (j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {

   if (arr[j].firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(arr[j + 1].firstName) > 0) { // ascending
                                                                           // sort
    temp = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; // swapping
    arr[j + 1] = temp;
    flag = true;
     }
     }
     }
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    System.out.println(arr[k].firstName +" "+arr[k].lastName);
   }
   }

    }
```

Then I used a simple program to print all of the names, first in the order that they were given, then in order by last name and then in order by first name.

```
 import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  public class SortNameApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

    try {
  int namesCount = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
  Person[] arr = new Person[namesCount];
       String line = null;
       int i = 0;
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           line = scanner.nextLine();
           Person person = new Person();
  person.firstName = line.split(" ")[0];
           person.lastName = line.substring(person.firstName.length(),
                   line.length()).trim();
           arr[i] = person;
           System.out.println(arr[i].firstName +" "+arr[i].lastName);
           i++;
  }
    System.out.println("---------SORT BY LAST NAME---------");
       new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 1);// sort by last name
       System.out.println("---------SORT BY FIRST NAME---------");
       new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 2);// sort by first name
   } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  }
```

I wanted to create a GUI that does all three things with different buttons printing in different relative JtextFields, however when i go to print it out, only one name is printed out on to the jtextfield, even though the the text file has about 30 names in it. this is what i am calling under the "load file" button

```
public void Read() {
   try {
   String file = filename.getText();
   int filesize = file.length();

     Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file));


  int namesCount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
  Person[] arr = new Person[namesCount];
       String line = null;
       int i = 0;
  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
           line = input.nextLine();
           Person person = new Person();
   person.firstName = line.split(" ")[0];
           person.lastName = line.substring(person.firstName.length(),
                   line.length()).trim();
           arr[i] = person;
           display.setText(arr[i].firstName +" "+arr[i].lastName);
           i++;
```

For the sorting i tried to do this, but it still does not work properly:

```
display2.setText(new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 2));
```

here

What is the proper way to do something like this?

This is my GUI so far

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;



public class SortNamesGUI extends JFrame  {


private final LayoutManager layout;
private final LayoutManager layout2;
private JButton loadButton;
private JTextField filename;
private JTextArea display;
private JTextArea display2;
private JTextArea display3;

public SortNamesGUI()
{
super("Sorting Names");
setLayout(new BorderLayout());



JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
layout = new FlowLayout();
buttonPanel.setLayout(layout);


JButton LoadFile = new JButton("Load File");
JButton FirstName = new JButton("Sort First Name");
JButton LastName = new JButton("Sort Last Name");
filename = new JTextField("Data file", 15);

buttonPanel.add(filename);
buttonPanel.add(LoadFile);
buttonPanel.add(FirstName);
buttonPanel.add(LastName);


JPanel DisplayPanel = new JPanel();
layout2 = new GridLayout(1,3);
DisplayPanel.setLayout(layout2);
display = new JTextArea("Unsorted list");
display2 = new JTextArea("Sorted based on first name");
display3 = new JTextArea("Sorted based on last name");

DisplayPanel.add(display);
DisplayPanel.add(display2);
DisplayPanel.add(display3);
DisplayPanel.add(new JScrollPane(display));
DisplayPanel.add(new JScrollPane(display2));
DisplayPanel.add(new JScrollPane(display3));

add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(DisplayPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


LoadFile.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Read();    }
}
);

}

/*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
Read();
}*/

public void Read() {
   try {
   String file = filename.getText();
   int filesize = file.length();

     Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file));


  int namesCount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
  Person[] arr = new Person[namesCount];
       String line = null;
       int i = 0;
  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
           line = input.nextLine();
           Person person = new Person();
  person.firstName = line.split(" ")[0];
           person.lastName = line.substring(person.firstName.length(),
                   line.length()).trim();
           arr[i] = person;
           display.setText(arr[i].firstName +" "+arr[i].lastName);
           i++;
           person.toString();


     }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }


  public void SoftFirstName() {
  String file = filename.getText();
   int filesize = file.length();

     Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file));

  int namesCount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
   Person[] arr = new Person[namesCount];
   new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 2);// sort by first name
    display2.setText(new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 2));




 }






public static void main(String[] args) {
 SortNamesGUI testing= new SortNamesGUI();
  testing.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  testing.setSize(620, 180);
  testing.setVisible(true);



}
}
```

Comment: Not going to look at this dump of code until it is formatting with correct indentation

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: Your code is impossible to read. How do *you* even read and understand it? Or maybe you don't? Please format (indent) code to correctly show the code structure and make it human readable.

Comment: The long answer is, yes - well kind of, the short answer, and the one you'd better off following is, no - you'll need to design a API which does what you want, but returns the information you want to display so you can decided on how it is to be displayed

Comment: You should show the GUI code which you wrote. Also as others have said, you should learn about accepted formatting conventions in order to help others read your code better.

Comment: Because `display.setText(arr[i].firstName +" "+arr[i].lastName);` will always set the text to a single name. If it even works.

Comment: Use `display.append(arr[i].firstName + " " + arr[i].lastName);` instead of `display.setText(arr[i].firstName + " " + arr[i].lastName);` - Now clean up your code and you question, because I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out what it is you're actually trying to ask - You're not trying to update a `JTextField`, but a `JTextArea`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not going to look at it until it's indented AND shortened(a lot)

Answer (score 0):

```
display2.setText(new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 2));
```

If you have tried this, you most likely get a compiler error. This is because the `sortNames()` method returns `void` but the `setText()` method requires a `String` argument. You need to modify `sortNames()` to return the sorted array rather than printing it out directly. In your original code, `main()` should get the sorted array and then print it. This is an example of what we call the Single Responsibility Principle. Each method should be responsible for a single task. In this case, your `sortNames()` does two things: 1. Sort the array and 2. Print the sorted array. If you separate these two tasks into separate methods, it will make your job a lot easier when you convert it to a GUI.

Once you have separated these two tasks, you will then need to decide how you want the names to appear in the JTextAray. I can think of at least two solutions:

1. Convert the entire array to a String and display the result in the JTextArea. This should be very easy to implement, but the output will have a list of names separated by commas inside square brackets.
2. Add each name one at a time to the JTextArea. Note that `setText()` will completely replace the entire contents of the JTextArea with the given text. I suggest look at [the documentation for JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to find another method that will be useful for your purposes.